# block redirect link to login in joomla and add a popup instead of that

Tags: authentication, joomla

In joomla the default function if a guest clicks a link with a registered access level, is to redirect guest to the login page.
Is there a way to show a popup instead, for all of registered access level links?

For example it redirects to

```
your.com/login.html
```

But i want to show a login-button before the guest is redirected.

I found another template where it works like this, but it wont work in my own template. How can I do it in my template?

```
if(JFactory::getUser()->guest) {
//do user logged out stuff
}
else {
//do user logged in stuff
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "click with a registered access lvl"? Do you mean if someone clicks a link that leads to an article with access restrictions? So that for any link with restricted access, you want a popup instead of being redirected to the login page?

Comment: yes exactly but not only for an article with access restrictions, exactly for all parts of website with access restriction of guests

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple fix. The problem is that when it is added, you dont really have information about where a link leads to. If you create an article that is public, and you add a link to an article that is restricted, then joomla does not check this when you add the link.

In the event that joomla can know this beforehand, like restricted menu items, or listing of article links in a category, restricted links will not be displayed to a guest user.

If you want to try to change the behaviour like you want to, then I would consider in what situation this actually happens. If it is links in articles that is the main problem, then the best would be if the editors, when adding links to restricted content, also added a predefined class or something to this link. Then use JQuery to disable the link and display a popup on click. A similar approach could be used in other contexts.

Comment: no not in the way you describe , i know taht joomla does that like you describe , i want to do it for all system parts like links of articles that are restricted parts like profile , comments and other parts that need registertion